# open external links in safari.app from UIWebView xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

i have created UIwebView and name it :webveiw 
in ViewController.h i add the following code to open external link in safari :

```
-(BOOL) webview:(UIWebView *)webview shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {
    if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[inRequest URL]];
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

when run it does not working where i did wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try set a delegate:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    myWebView.delegate = self;
}
```

And add protocol UIWebViewDelegate:

```
@interface yourViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate>
```